# Как установить dkim-milter на centos 7

Tags: centos, dkim

Пытаюсь установить dkim-milter на сервер с centos 7.
Команда yum install dkim-milter
неизменно выдает "No package dkim-milter available"

```
    # yum install dkim-milter
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
No package dkim-milter available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Пробовал подключать разные репозитории epel remi rpmforge - результат везде один.
Подскажите как установить его.

Comment: судя по содержимому http://mirror.logol.ru/epel//7/x86_64/d/, такого пакета в репозитории *epel* нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно информации от [разработчиков](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dkim-milter/):

> NOTE: dkim-milter has been replaced by OpenDKIM

перевод:

> примечание: dkim-milter был заменён пакетом opendkim

---

значит, вам надо устанавливать пакет *opendkim*.